# How do I write an error out to the client in a cmd line pre-commit hook app?

Tags: c#, svn, command-line, pre-commit-hook

I'm writing a pre-commit hook in C# and I know I have to return 1 for failure and 0 for sucess, but I cant get it to write any message out to the client.  Currently I'm using

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var repository = args[0];
    var transaction = args[1];       

    // TODO: do stuff and return 1 or 0 appropriately 

    Console.WriteLine("This message should go to the client");

    return 1;
}
```

Tortoise is just giving the feedback:

> Error: Commit failed (details follow):
>   Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit
>   hook (exit code 1) with no output.

How do I make my command line application provide feedback to the svn client (tortoise in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Console.WriteLine` to `Console.Error.WriteLine`